# How to declare sub-modules in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

When working on large projects in AngularJS, I found that I like organizing code by functionality.
That means that when I have some recognizable functionality X (especially if it is reusable) I create directory X and put into it all controllers, services and other parts that belong to that functionality. I also declare a new module called X and assign everything in directory X to that module.

**Directory structure** would then look something like this:

```
scripts/
  app.js
  controllers/
  services/
  directives/
  filters/
  X/
    controllers/
    services/
    directives/
    filters/
```

In **app.js** there is a main module declaration:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['X']);
```

All controllers etc. in X/ belong to module 'X', which means I fetch module 'X' like this in those files:

```
var X = angular.module('X');
```

**What I am not sure how to do is where to declare module 'X'?**

Some ideas I had:

- I could declare it in one of the controllers/services/... and fetch it in other controllers etc. but that does not sound right because I do not see any logic how to pick that controller/service/... among others, and also then I have to take care to include it in index.html before others. I find this idea **bad**.
- I can put declaration in app.js, so app.js would now look like
  `angular.module('myApp', ['X']);
  angular.module('X', [/*some dependencies could go here*/]);`
  I find this idea **better** than the previous one, however I do not like that module declaration is outside of directory X.
- In directory X/ I create file main.js and put declaration of module X in it. I have to be careful to include this file in index.html before other files from directory X/.
  I like this solution the **best**.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. Third option is the **best** solution. First option will definitely give a pain in the neck. Second option adds a dependency of module X in the main app, which is not desirable. You would want your module to be self-contained. So third option is the best solution.

Here is the [best practice recommendations from Google](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) which you are actually trying to adhere to. :) Moreover, it will also be great for you (as suggested by Google's best practice) to not separate the files by artifacts, which means you do not need controllers, directives, etc dir structure as below. Also note partials, CSS and even tests are in the component are contained in the component/module directory. Hence the module is totally contained and independent, which helps in reusability:

```
sampleapp/ 
  app.css
  app.js                        
  app-controller.js
  app-controller_test.js
  components/
    bar/                                "bar" describes what the service does
      bar.js
      bar-service.js
      bar-service_test.js
      bar-partial.html
    foo/                                "foo" describes what the directive does
      foo.js
      foo-directive.js
      foo-directive_test.js
      foo-partial.html
  index.html
```

I hope this will be helpful.